# Set max time for capturevideo - Codename One

Tags: video-capture, capture, codenameone

How would I go about setting the maximum time a video can be recorded in codename one using capturevideo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality isn't supported by the capture API at this time. You can use [native interfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to implement it per platform but that might take some work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the "accessing the native code..." on Code Name One's website in the "How do I?".

Comment: Did you ever implement this Sean? I would be interested in using the lib :)